# sanctify or speak of sanctity... of God

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, terminology

While reading a text the following question occurred to me:

---

Do we sanctify God? Or do we speak of sanctity of God?

Actually I was reading a text in which I found the following:

> ...while praising You, o God, we sanctify You...

---

It doesn't sound to fit best, does it? I think it is God who sanctifies men and things. Thus, it may be:

> ...while praising You, o God, we speak of Your sanctity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about theology.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey quite a lot of language is shaped by theology. Plenty of people say "oh my god" or use phrases like "the gospel truth" even though they don't believe in a god. Although there are religious meanings to the word in question it is essentially about the difference between a verb and an adjective.

Comment: This is about language. Theological language, but language, not theology. It should not be closed, and if closed I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Although there are religious meanings to the word you are asking about, this question is essentially about the difference between a related noun and an adjective. I hope that people can accept this question and answer regardless of their personal religious or secular beliefs.**

*Sanctity* (noun) is the state of being holy.

*Sanctify* (verb) is the action of making something holy.

"Holy" in Christianity means *spiritual cleanness*, or the state of being clean in God's eyes. The Bible describes God as holy himself, so you could rightly speak of "the sanctity of God" to mean his permanent state or condition. When the Bible speaks of humans *sanctifying God* or *sanctifying God's name* it means actions of people which *honour* God and his name.

You might ask why does someone need to sanctify (or make clean) something that is already holy (or clean)? Imagine that someone wrongly accuses you of a crime - it might be said that the person has "smeared your name". Someone else, however, gives a character testimony in your favour - they might be said to have "cleared your name". The whole time you remained innocent. This is why in the Bible and Christianity humans can be spoken of as "sanctifying" God when they advocate that he is holy, even though a core teaching of the faith is that he already is holy.

You are also correct though that God can "sanctify" things. Another core belief of Christianity is that Christians can become clean in God's eyes by putting faith in Christ.

Comment: the state of being holy is holiness, too.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example uses *sanctify* in a sense which is now obsolete, but which the OED attests from about 1450,

> 3a. To honour as holy; to ascribe holiness to; = *hallow* v.1 3. *Obsolete*.

The OED gives an example from Shakespeare's *All's Well That Ends Well* (1623):

> Whilst I from farre, His name with zealous feruour sanctifie.

*Hallow*, similarly, can mean to make something holy, but can also mean to venerate something as holy.

These are specialized meanings limited to theological writing, and have been for some time, but it is not uncommon to speak of sanctifying God, God's words, or God's name in Christian writings (and I see a few examples from Jewish writings as well).

Answer (score 1):

Phrases such as "Sanctify God's name" and "Sanctify your name" (when addressing God) or "Sanctify your name and keep it holy" and many variants, all in he sense suggested by @choster are **very** common in the English-language liturgy published for use by Jewish congregations of the Reform and  Re-constructionist denominations. The Temple I used to attend  switched from Reform to Reconstructionist, and switched prayer books, but these ph5rases were so common in the High Holy Days services from both sets of books that I couldn't begin to count the number of times that they appeared.

Each Jewish congregation  is independent, and no one has to use the published liturgy texts, but many Temples do use them. This wording is not recent, but it remains in active use in this context at least.